# PHP run linux "less" command via exec - binary file warning

Tags: php, linux, pdf, less-unix

I have to convert some PDF files to TXT. I end up with "less" command, because for example pdftotext has some problems with tables in PDF. The problem is that when I ran the command from exec function (or shell_exec/system), less just showing me information, that selected PDF is binary file and result file is just TXT with PDF data in it. But when I do the same thing normally in terminal, everything is ok. I also tried to login as www_data user and ran command as this user, but there is also no problem.

Command:

```
$ less /var/www/original.pdf > /var/www/new.txt
```

PHP code:

```
exec("less -f /var/www/original.pdf > /var/www/new.txt 2>&1");
```

Result from PHP exec:

```
"/var/www/original.pdf" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

The "-f" option in exec command is there because then you don't need to press "y" for "yes, I want to see it anyway."

`set | grep less` yields:

```
LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
            Lossless LZW RLE Zip' -- "$cur" ));
                _apport_parameterless
                _apport_parameterless
                _apport_parameterless
                _apport_parameterless
_apport_parameterless ()
```

Comment: I don't mean less css, but linux application less.

Comment: Is that warning what comes up in that new.txt file?

Comment: Can you post what is returned if you use `shell_exec()` instead of `exec()`?

Comment: @SimonGermain: if convert is done by PHP, in new.txt file are original PDF data (not clean text which I want).

Comment: @loler: shell_exec giving me the same result as exec unfortunately.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking. Where do you see that message when you call exec()? In the file you're trying to convert or as a console output?

Comment: @SimonGermain Sorry.. There are two options. If I keep the "-f" option in "less ...." command, then I'dont see this warning, because it is confirmed "by force" http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm and in my new.txt file are PDF binary data. If I remove this -f option, then this warning is in my new.txt file.

Comment: Could you do me a favor and give me the output of the following command from your shell: `set | grep less`

Comment: Of course. I'll update original post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, your console is able to display a PDF file with `less` because you have an input preprocessor installed, like `lesspipe` or `lessfile`. The way to make `less` use those preprocessor is by reading an environment variable called LESSOPEN, which points to the `lesspipe` and `lessfile` script.

There might be a way your webserver, through environment variables and shell commands, might be able to replicate this behavior so that your calls to `less` parse PDFs properly.

What I would suggest would be to call a bash script to do the conversion for you instead of calling `less` directly. That way, your bash script would be able to set the appropriate environment variables and execute the appropriate commands to convert your PDF files to a readable output.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval $(lesspipe)
less $1 > $2 2>&1
```

Then, from PHP, call that script like this:

```
exec("/path/to/your/script/script.sh /var/www/original.pdf /var/www/new.txt");
```

If it doesn't work, try changing `eval $(lesspipe)` to `eval $(lessfile)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, less is an interactive program to read text streams. In this context you should use `cat` instead. This or course won't work either since PDF is a binary format as opposed to text based.

Why don't you use a pdf to text converter like `pdftotext`?

Comment: Because pdftotext doesn't convert some PDF files properly. For example if there is a table which splits PDF file to two sides, pdftotext result handles left side on top of TXT file and right side on the bottom of result TXT file. But less result keeps the formating of that table, just replace "white space" of table with spaces. So you can see which entries from left side are on the same line with entries from right side.

Answer (score 0):

How was the PHP code executed?  On the command line, via `php file.php` or by a Web server when you hit it with a browser `http://servername/something/file.php`?

One guess is that the `less` you execute when doing it on the command line is not the same `less` as when the PHP code is run.